# why 500 - internal server error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pusher-js

```
const form = document.getElementById('vote-form')
form.addEventListener('submit',e => {
  let choice = document.querySelector('input[name=os]:checked').value;
  let data = {os: choice};

  fetch("http://localhost:3000/poll",{ // *** getting error here
    method:'post',
    body:JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: new Headers({
      'Content-Type':'application/json'
    })
  }).then(res => res.json()).then((data) => {console.log(data)}).catch(err => console.log(err))    
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Here`s the backend code: Its my main router file, where all related routes are placed

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const Pusher = require('pusher')

let pusher=new Pusher({
  appId:'*******',
  key:'*****',
  secret:'******',
  cluster:'*****',
  encrypted:true
});

router.get('/',(req,res) => { //it actually means /poll (as mentioned in app.js)
  res.send('polling starts');
})

router.post('/',(req,res)=>{
pusher.trigger('os-poll','os-vote',{
  points: 1,
  os: req.body.os
});
res.json({success:true,message:"thanks for voting"})
});

module.exports=router
```

I am getting Internal Server Error - 500 Status code. Why so?? What could be the possible reason?

Comment: Please show your back-end code.

Comment: @Kevin added the same.

Comment: I saw your code has a character "1" before module.exports.

Comment: @Kevin I am facing issues in that promise code. Fetch is not returning anything I guess. Or it is not working as it is supposed to.

Comment: If you get 500 error, it should be your back-end code has some problem. I did not use pusher library before. I suggest you remove the pusher.trigger from your back-end code and just simply send back some text to see whether it works. If it does, you should take a look the document of pusher and make it right.

Comment: Let me try. That's a great idea.

Comment: Try adding breakpoints to your app.get / app.post and see if they're even triggered.

Comment: @Kevin yes it worked but when I included that trigger method again, I get an error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

Comment: @JakeT. the main issue is in pusher.trigger method, I am unable to figure out this one `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

Comment: Sorry. I do not know the pusher library. Please reorganize your post and address the main issue. So, somebody who familiars with pusher will answer it.

Comment: @Kevin thanks for the effort buddy

Comment: If you updated your code, show the update. The symbol you've posted shouldn't be there in the code you've shown.

Comment: I think the options you're passing aren't valid.  Try changing your `{points:1, os: req.body.os}` to `{message:"test message"}`

Comment: And if that's the case, you've gotta find the proper syntax to pass the attributes you want.  Likely data?  `{message:"test message", data: { points:1, os: req.body.os}}`

Comment: we need to send JSON data so, I am bound to stringify, I cannot send an object as suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to use `body-parser` package for the same.